# How to communicate between entities using websockets in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, notifications, spring-websocket

I have been researching websockets and found an informative example on github that I have begun to implement in my own project.
Link:
https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-web-socket-user-notifications

I suppose I have many questions regarding this but I will try not to overload you guys.

1. I intent to use websockets for friend request notifications (accept/decline) between the users but at the moment passing messages to and from is substantial. Would you recommend the websocket approach with spring or are there easier/more practical technologies when implementing notifications?
2. At the moment my "notification" entity is the exact same as in the tutorial, is it good practice to make "notification" a bean and persist these messages in the database I am using, or is this not applicable when using websockets?
3. In the controller class a new "notification" object is being created passing the parameters "hello" and "UserA" , how would I go about passing a hardcoded username from my database into this method so the notifications will be sent to "g@gmail.com" instead of UserA, since the ways that seem obvious to me have not caused any errors but has done virtually nothing (so it seems) and no message is being passed.

Questions 1 and 2 are advice, question 3 is a code related question

Here is my controller code (the relevant parts) :

```
//websocket

  @Autowired
  private NotificationService notificationService;

  /**
   * GET  /  -> show the index page.
   */
  @RequestMapping("/index2")
  public String index2() {
    return "index2";
  }

  /**
   * GET  /notifications  -> show the notifications page.
   */
  @RequestMapping("/notifications")
  public String notifications() {
    return "notifications";
  }

  /**
   * POST  /some-action  -> do an action.
   * 
   * After the action is performed will be notified UserA.
   */
  @RequestMapping(value = "/some-action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<?> someAction() {

    // Do an action here
    // ...

   //me messing about to try and map the correct user (ignore)
    UserLogin testuser = userRepository.findByUserName("g@gmail.com");
    String name = testuser.getUserName();


    // Send the notification to "UserA" (by username)
    notificationService.notify(
      new Notification("hello"), // notification object
      "g@gmail.com"                   // username
    );

    // Return an http 200 status code
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
  /////////////////////////////
```

The notification service (note that i changed the variable String username to String userName in a desperate testing attempt):

```
@Service
public class NotificationService {

  // The SimpMessagingTemplate is used to send Stomp over WebSocket messages.
  @Autowired
  private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

  /**
   * Send notification to users subscribed on channel "/user/queue/notify".
   *
   * The message will be sent only to the user with the given username.
   * 
   * @param notification The notification message.
   * @param username The username for the user to send notification.
   */
  public void notify(Notification notification, String userName) {
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
      userName, 
      "/queue/notify", 
      notification
    );
    return;
  }

}
```

I didn't include the WebSecurityConfig.java class from the tutorial into my project as I have an already existing one. (This maybe where the problem lies)
Here is my websecurityconfig file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
       UserLoginRepository userLoginRepository;


    //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/registeruser").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")

     @Autowired
     DataSource dataSource;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/registeruser").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
                    .permitAll();
            http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
        }



    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        //authorities at the moment is the manager i.e. 'Manager' from user_login

           auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
          .usersByUsernameQuery("select user_name,password,user_status from user_login where user_name=?")
          .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_name,password, 'Manager'  from user_login where user_name=?");          

}

    }
```

Here is my userlogin model, this is the object I would like to receive the message instead of "UserA".

```
@Entity
public class UserLogin {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Long phone;
    private String userName;
    private String address;
    private String password;
    private boolean userStatus;
    private String userType;
    private String position;



    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     public Set<PlayerSeasonStat> playerStats;

    public UserLogin()
    {

    }


    public UserLogin(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, Long phone,
            String userName, String address, String password,
            boolean userStatus, String userType, String position,
            Set<PlayerSeasonStat> playerStats) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.address = address;
        this.password = password;
        this.userStatus = userStatus;
        this.userType = userType;
        this.position = position;
        this.playerStats = playerStats;
    }

////getters and setters
```

I am also getting some info on the console saying that there is one active thread in the sockJsScheduler :

```
2018-02-07 12:54:14.526  INFO 11776 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

Note that all other java/jsp/html pages are the same in my project as they are in the tutorial (except for the index.html page which I have renamed index2.html and amended this throughout the project, and obviously anything I have mentioned above.

If you require more code let me know as I don't want this to look like an essay!

Answer (score 0):

Update:
So I have messed around with my project and figured out that the reason the websocket technology was not able to communicate is because in my projects WebSecurityConfig.java class (which was completely different to the tutorials WebSecurityConfig.java class) I did not disable csrf, which obviously allows the websockets to communicate once disabled!

So I added:

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

into this method (in WebSecurityConfig):

```
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/registeruser").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
                    .permitAll();
            http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
```

And it worked!